# Can nDepend find methods containing a specific string

Tags: ndepend

I am trying to get a list of methods that call a REST api. These calls are scattered across a few projects. The common ground is that the all contain the string "/api/". Can CQLinq find these methods?

Ultimately I would love to get a list of these, and then pull a list of their Calling methods.

Comment: Not for now, NDepend doesn't gather yet string literal values to make them queryable